# Simple React Redux starter pack | generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, generator, redux

Am looking for simple easy to understand starter pack with React Redux. Eslint linting, webpack devserver hot reloading and test runner.

I want something more simple then react starter pack which is not providing comments in code and documentation not as understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [generator-react-webpack](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack), a React generator for [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)

> Generator-React-Webpack will help you build new React projects using modern technologies.
>
> Out of the box it comes with support for:
>
> - Webpack
> - ES2015 via Babel-Loader
> - Different supported style languages (sass, scss, less, stylus)
> - Style transformations via PostCSS
> - Automatic code linting via esLint
> - Ability to unit test components via Karma and Mocha/Chai

[More info.](http://newtriks.com/2013/12/31/automating-react-with-yeoman-and-grunt/)

Comment: I will have a look at the https://github.com/stylesuxx/generator-react-webpack-redux which inherits from this generator.